# PhantomJS and Flow?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, static-typing

Static typing is great. Is it possible to get [Facebook's Flow](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1505962329687926/flow-a-new-static-type-checker-for-javascript/) to work with PhantomJS? Attempting `flow check` on the following snippet:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system');

if (system.args.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: ' + system.args[0] + ' <some URL> <depth>');
  phantom.exit();
}
```

Yields the error:

```
test1.js:4:1,7: identifier phantom
Unknown global name
```

I'm not sure how to set up `flow` so that it understands the environment that PhantomJS is working in. Documentation on `flow` seems pretty sparse --- I assume that the `.flowconfig` file needs to be edited, but I can't find anything about how to set it correctly, or about what environment PhantomJS needs to run in.